# Reset project directory of apache web server virtual host having let's encrypt ssl certificate installed

Tags: server, apache2, lets-encrypt

I have a website `www.example.com` that is hosted on apache2 web server in `/var/www/example.com` directory and the virtual host config file is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public
    <Directory /var/www/example.com/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml >
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have installed let's encrypt certificate for this domain.

Now I have to change configuration settings and the config file should be like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/dist //here is the change
    <Directory /var/www/example.com/dist/> //here is the change
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml >
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have edited the config file and ran command `certbot --apache -d example.com -d www.example.com`.
Chose `reinstall` and `renew` both options and the installation was successful in both cases. But when I go to `example.com` then it shows `404 error`.
How can I solve my problem?

Comment: HTTPS uses port 443, not port 80.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS uses port 443, not port 80. Port 443 is closed. You need to add a new virtual host to handle HTTPS request

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        #ServerAlias www.example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/dist
        LogLevel debug  ssl:info
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/yout/cert
        SSLCertificateKeyFile //path/to/yout/key
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

If you check `ports.conf` under `/etc/apache2`, you will see this:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Apache2 will open port 443 when the SSL module is enabled. So remember to run:

```
sudo a2dismod ssl
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```